# Run script on remote kernel

Tags: python, anaconda, remote-access, spyder, remote-server

I would how to run a script using a remote kernel ? I have everything set and did connect successfully to the kernel from Spyder but I'm getting an error when executing the script. It says file (script file) not found. Is there a way to just run the script without copying it and all the data files ?
Just use the remote kernel for calculation ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) The only way to evaluate a local file in a remote kernel is to run it as a cell. For that, you need to add this comment before the first line with code in your file

```
# %%
import foo
...
```

Then, you need to press `Ctrl+Enter` in the Editor to send the entire contents of your file to the console.